# How to use logical operations with GPIO of raspberry pi

Tags: raspbian, python, rpi.gpio

I am using two pins of GPIO as input and I want to check whether both are high or low at a time so I want to use a logical AND operation to check the status of both the pins, but I coudnt get that right as I have wrote few lines as below.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(11,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(12,GPIO.OUT)

GPIO.output(11,1)
GPIO.output(12,1)
time.sleep(1)
GPIO.output(11,0)
GPIO.output(12,0)
while True:
  if(GPIO.output(11) && GPIO.output(12) == 1)
    print"both the leds are ON"
  else:
    print"both the LED's are OFF"
```

But this is'nt working. So please help me. How can I get this logical operations done? Error I am facing is 'syntax error'.

Answer (score 2):

I have taken some liberties with your code.  In particular I changed from BOARD mode to BCM mode as it was easier for me to test.  I tested by changing the GPIO levels outside the script.

Notes

1. && is logical and in C etc.  Python uses and.
2. There is no point in changing the LED level twice before the while loop.  The while loop will not see those transitions.
3. You can read the level of a GPIO set as an output.
4. I added a time.sleep(0.1) in the while loop so other programs get a
   chance to run.

.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(11,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(12,GPIO.OUT)

GPIO.output(11,1)
GPIO.output(12,0)

while True:
  if GPIO.input(11) == 1 and GPIO.input(12) == 1:
    print("both the leds are ON")
  elif GPIO.input(11) == 0 and GPIO.input(12) == 0:
    print("both the LED's are OFF")
  else:
    print("one LED is ON, one is OFF")

  time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: thanks @joan it cleared my doubt,i have actually used 'and' and tried but yours worked well

Comment: Hi, i am using pyfirmata to connect to arduino 2560/arduino mega,I need all 53 I/o of arduino for blinkng Led but i can only use upto  13 pins of it.what should i do to access all the I/o pins with my raspberry pi.I have used 'board.digital[14].write(1)'.it is showing error:' index out of range' .Please help me solving this or atleast suggest me how can i use all the pins or the maximum pins.thanks

Comment: @SharathVedala I have no knowledge of firmata or pyfirmata.  You probably ought to open a new question and give the relevant details.

Comment: but today i cannot ask a new question.Its ok

Comment: @SharathVedala Someone may answer if they read your comment but a new question (tomorrow?) will be seen by more people.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to read an input ? Syntax error was due to because you forgot to put `:` after your `if` statement.

Here, you can use this,

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO 
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD) 
GPIO.setup(11,GPIO.IN) 
GPIO.setup(12,GPIO.IN)

while True: 
    if(GPIO.input(11) == 1 and GPIO.input(12) == 1):
        print"both the leds are ON" 
    else: 
        print"both the LED's are OFF"
```

For more info: refer to this [documentation](http://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/BasicUsage/).

Hope it helps.